# Vue select onchange prop to child component not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two components. Component 1:

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group">Category</label>

    <select name="category" v-model="category" @change="setCategory(category)" class="form-control select-group" id="category">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<tags-multiselect :categoryId="category"></tags-multiselect>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      category: 1,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setCategory(selected) {
      this.category = selected;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Component 2:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categoryId'],
        data () {
         return {
           category_ids: this.categoryId
        }
        },
        created() {
        axios.post('/tags', { category_id: this.categoryId })
          .then((response) => {
             //
          })
          .catch((err) => {

          })
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I select option from first component, I not update `category_id` on second component with other id I get only `1` id. And when I send axios request with category_id I send always only first param `1`.  How I can resolve this? How I can refresh the second component with new selected data from select field?

Comment: remove `@change="setCategory(category)"` it's not needed because you have  `v-model="category"`

Answer (score 0):

props need to be kebab case in the template.

Try `<tags-multiselect :category-id="category"></tags-multiselect>`

Also, you don't need to redefine props in the data. Get rid of `category_ids` in component 2, it will just confuse things.

Then, Vue makes it very easy to extract your state from your components. Shared state (categoryId) and operations on shared state ( `axios.post(...)` ) would be much happier in global scope, according to me !

Comment: Can you please give example global scope?